# RVM install without prompt

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to script an install of Ruby and RVM but I am running into some issues. When I try to run:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-head
```

RVM shows some text and asks me to press "q" to continue. Since this is going to be part of a script, I need to figure out how to continue without having to press "q".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rvm in interactive mode might ask questions, to avoid them use rvm in binary mode, there are two ways:

```
command rvm install 1.9.3 # when rvm was sourced
```

and:

```
$rvm_path/bin/rvm install 1.9.3 # should work always
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure this out for a week now

Comment: @mpapis - Any idea how to do this on the initial install? See: http://serverfault.com/questions/412740/skipping-a-press-certain-key-to-continue-in-a-bash-script/412741#412741 Would really appreciate the help!